# Javascript split the email address - Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I have a string like:

```
'"test@test.com, "Ragland Raja, II" <moses.jelsey@gmail.com>, "'
```

I want to separate this string into an array like,

```
array[0] = test@test.com
array[1] = "Ragland Raja, II" <moses.jelsey@gmail.com>
```

Can you please give any suggestions?

Comment: Your strings are not valid strings.

Comment: Use the .split() method. Can you show us what you've attempted so far?

Comment: aa.match(/"(.*?)"(.*?),|(.*?)$/g); I used this regex but not woking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd have to accomplish this in pieces. First replace the comma+space within quotations so it doesn't mess up your split operation. Here I've replaced the space with an underscore.

```
str.replace(/(".*,)( )(.*")/g, '$1_$3');   
  // 'test@test.com, "Ragland Raja,_II" <moses.jelsey@gmail.com>,  '
```

Then you just run a regular split operation:

```
str.split(", ");
  // ["test@test.com", ""Ragland Raja,_II" <moses.jelsey@gmail.com>", ""]
```

After that, go back and swap out the `,_` within quotes in each item. Here's the full code below.

### Solution

```
var str = 'test@test.com, "Ragland Raja, II" <moses.jelsey@gmail.com>, ';
str = str.replace(/(".*,)( )(.*")/g, '$1_$3');

var arr = str.split(", ");
arr.forEach(function(el, i, array){
    array[i] = el.replace(",_", ", ");
});

  // arr = ["test@test.com", ""Ragland Raja, II" <moses.jelsey@gmail.com>", ""]
```

Comment: Hello there, Thanks a lot. Its works great.\n
I just changed your concept to support my requirement.\n

Actually Sometime I get the string like\n"test1@test.com,test2@test.com".(after comma no space)
So I made the code like below,

var t1 = str.replace(/(".*,)( )(.*")/g, '$1_comma_$3').replace(/,_comma_/g, '_comma_').split(',');

for (idx=0 ; idx<iLen ; idx++) {
t2 = t1[idx].trim();
t2 = currentItem.replace("_comma_", ",");
}

Please let me know if you have any other better option for this.
Thanks again,
Ramesh

Comment: @Ramesh Raja - Great! Glad I could help.

Comment: Hi Walton, if my string is like this, str = '"testFN testLN, II" <test1@test.com>, "testFN testLN, Cal" <test2@test.com>'; .replace() only replacing the last instance. Regex: str.replace(/(".*,)(.*")/g, '$1_comma_$2'). Here I used /g, but still its replaces only last instance. Could you please help me out this?

Comment: Getting o/p like the below: "testFN testLN, II" <test1@test.com>, "testFN testLN_comma_ Cal" <test2@test.com>